# Access SpringBoot hosted URL in mobile

Tags: java, spring, mobile, spring-boot

I have written a spring boot app which is hosted and running in my localhost (Desktop).

But when I try to access the url from my mobile, it says connection time out. I have even configured my port in Firewall.

I have spring boot hosted in my desktop and my mobile connects internet through a pci card in my computer.

I can access the url from my desktop browser but not my mobile browser.

I have done an ipconfig and have used my wifi ip address and lan ip address, both are not working, I am not using localhost from my mobile.

Comment: To access the app via your mobile you have to know the IP of your desktop. Google your IP then try to access the URL using that IP instead of localhost. As for example: `168.1.1.10/url` instead of `localhost/url` where `168.1.1.10` is your IP address. If your app is running on port `8080`, then include the port also. like `168.1.1.10:8080/url`.

Comment: i have done an ipconfig and have used my wifi ip address and lan ip address, both are not working, I am not using localhost from my mobile, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: try this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The problem is, internet to my computer comes through a LAN cable and I have added a wifi pci card to give access to my mobile. The answer in the link may work if your mobile and desktop are connected to the same wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with ngrok.

https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

It lets you expose your local machine webserver to internet.